# Get the list of available characters from the keyboard

Tags: objective-c

Hi,
I would like to get the list of all available characters from the keyboard (Digital Alphabetical) in order to create a NSArray.

```
TISInputSourceRef source = TISCopyCurrentKeyboardInputSource(); 
 NSLog(@"languages: %@", TISGetInputSourceProperty(source,       kTISPropertyInputSourceLanguages));
 NSLog(@"localized name: %@", TISGetInputSourceProperty(source, kTISPropertyLocalizedName));
```

I use these lines, but I can't find the right function to list the characters.

I also tried this line :

```
NSLog(@"List: %@", TISGetInputSourceProperty(source, kTISPropertyUnicodeKeyLayoutData));
```

Comment: That last line seems like the right thing to call (`TISPropertyUnicodeKeyLayoutData`). What was the problem with it?

Comment: Hello and thank you. I have not managed to convert the result of this function, and I have found no valid response.

Answer (score 0):

Would you be able to get it from calling:

```
TISGetInputSourceProperty(source, kTISPropertyUnicodeKeyLayoutData);
```

That will return the 'uchr' data for the keyboard layout (if it exists), as a `CFDataRef`. You can read about the layout of the 'uchr' data [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/reference/Unicode_Utilities_Ref/uu_app_uchr/uu_app_uchr.html). You'll need to get the bytes from the `CFDataRef`, probably by calling something like `CFDataGetBytes()` or `CFDataGetBytePtr()`.

Comment: I do not know how to read the information contained in the CFDataRef. I've added the new lines below.

Comment: What you've got is correct. You've gotten the 'uchr' data into a buffer. Now you can decode it using [these docs that describe the format](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/reference/Unicode_Utilities_Ref/uu_app_uchr/uu_app_uchr.html).

Comment: This is exactly what I want to know, but I fails to use this code.
do you have an example for me to display information contained in the buffer?

Comment: No, I don't. But the docs above describe the memory layout, so it shouldn't be too hard to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

```
TISInputSourceRef currentKeyboard = TISCopyCurrentKeyboardInputSource();
    CFDataRef uchr = (CFDataRef)TISGetInputSourceProperty(currentKeyboard, kTISPropertyUnicodeKeyLayoutData);
    const UCKeyboardLayout *keyboardLayout = (const UCKeyboardLayout*)CFDataGetBytePtr(uchr);

    Byte* buffer =
    (Byte*) malloc (sizeof(Byte) * CFDataGetLength(uchr));



    CFDataGetBytes(
                   uchr,
                   CFRangeMake(0,CFDataGetLength(uchr)),
                   buffer
                   );
```

How to read the information contained in the CFDataRef ?